# How to change "File Type" on upload to Ubuntu One Cloud Storage

Tags: cloud

How do I change "File Type" on upload to Ubuntu One Cloud Storage. One avi file comes up as "video/x-msvideo" and the other comes up as "video/avi"  I would like them to both be the same.

Comment: As @dobey said,  *Are they encoded with different codecs?*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're asking exactly, but Ubuntu One doesn't really know anything about the MIME types. Do the files have different extensions? Are they encoded with different codecs?

Comment: No, they are both .avi.